# ヘルプセンターで重複したリンク先がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターで右側に表示されるナビゲーターメニュー(リンク一覧)の中に、リンク先が重複しているものがあります。
(ページによって表示が切り替わるので、例えば[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)を開いた場合の表示)

具体的には以下二つの項目でリダイレクトを挟んで最終的に「[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)」のページに飛ぶようになっています。

- スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の行動規範
  `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/conduct` (指定されたURL)
  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct (実際の遷移先)
- 親切になろうポリシー
  `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice`  (指定されたURL)
  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct (実際の遷移先)

"親切になろう(be nice.)"の方が古い標語？であるなら、こちらのリンクは取り除いてしまうのがいいのかなと思いますが如何でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リンク先が重複していた"親切になろうポリシー"の項目が削除されました。
（[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)の下から五番目にありましたリンクです。現在は削除済み。）